# Empty array when reading text file into array list

Tags: java, arrays

**Goal**: To fill an array with doubles from a text file.

**Error**: Empty array printed.

A small part of my text file which contains close to 500 numbers, I only need the values and not the "Z" at the start:

```
Z, 10.9123728, 5.3872839283, 11.30903923, 20.128192821, 3.8716134
```

My code:

```
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename1));
    ArrayList<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] nums = line.trim().split(",");
        
        if(inFile.hasNextDouble()) {
            float token = Float.parseFloat(nums[1].trim());
            values.add(token);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(values);
    inFile.close();
```

Comment: `inFile.hasNextDouble()` operates on the next line which again starts with a letter presumably. Instead you need to check if `nums[1]` can be parsed as a double or try to parse and react appropriately to an eventual exception.

Comment: Z is the only letter in the file, the rest is all number separated with a comma.

Comment: And those numbers are in new, separate lines?

Comment: Nope, they're just one after the other. No new lines.

Comment: Then the entire file is contained in `line` after the first `nextLine` call and `inFile.hasNextDouble()` will just return `false` all the time.

Comment: @luk2302 is correct. After the call to `nextLine()`, the file pointer is either at a 'Z' (if multiple lines) or the end of the file (if just one line). Instead of `if(inFile.hasNextDouble()) {`, loop through all the values in `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different routes here. Pick one. If you want to use `hasNextDouble` then you have to set up your `Scanner` to use a comma as a delimiter. However if given your current code, just abandon the hasNextDouble. NOTE that I did not test this, this is just me typing in the editor, so there could be syntax issues.

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename1));
ArrayList<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();

while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] nums = line.trim().split(",");
    
    for (String num : nums) {
        try {
            float float = Float.parseFloat(nums[i].trim());
            values.add(token);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // the 'z'
            continue;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(values);
inFile.close();
```